# How to inherit a class with the same name but in a different lib location?

Tags: perl, inheritance

I'm working with Perl and facing a challenge where I need to inherit a class with the same name (same package name) but located in different lib paths.

It seems like Perl only sees the package name and doesn't consider the lib paths when resolving inheritance. I tried manipulating @INC to change the order of the lib paths, but it hasn't helped.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or have any thoughts on how to inherit from a module with the same name but located in a different lib path?

Thanks in advance.

Samuel

Here's what I've attempted:

I've organized my modules like this:

- Kernel::Module1 in the main directory.
- Another Kernel::Module1 in the Custom/ directory.

In my main.pl code, I've included:

```
use lib '.';
use lib './Custom';
use Kernel::Module1;
```

And inside the module in /Custom, I tried:

```
{
  local @INC = ('.', @INC);
  use base 'Kernel::Module1';
}
```

Unfortunately, Perl returns the error: "Class 'Kernel::Module1' tried to inherit from itself."

Comment: You can't have two modules with the same name. Name it something else.

Comment: You shouldn't modify `@INC` in a module. Doesn't make sense, for starters. Perl is obviously already able to find the modules.

Comment: `.` is not the directory that contains the script. That's `$RealBin` from `use FindBin qw( $RealBin );`

Comment: Just for clarification, my use case doesn't allow me to use different names. The application has its own architecture to use 'custom' modules (basically overwriting the original module inside a different lib). So I would like to inherit from the 'original' module to avoid rewriting the whole module.

Comment: You can't have two modules with the same name. (They could have the same file name, but not the same package. That said, you have will have issues from having file names that differ from the package name, but you can work around those.) You might have to resort to monkey patching.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two modules with the same (package) name.

---

You have two files that follow this pattern:

```perl
package Kernel::Module1;

...

sub some_sub_or_method { ... }

...
```

This is basically equivalent to

```perl
package Kernel::Module1;

...

BEGIN { *some_sub_or_method = sub { ... }; }

...
```

So loading/executing the two files will result in

```perl
package Kernel::Module1;

...

BEGIN { *some_sub_or_method = sub { ... }; }

...

package Kernel::Module1;

...

BEGIN { *some_sub_or_method = sub { ... }; }

...
```

The second assignment will undo the first. You can't have two modules with the same (package) name.

---

If you want users of Kernel::Module1 to get a modified version of it, you will need to resort to monkey patching.

```perl
package My::Patch::Kernel::Module1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Kernel::Module1 qw( );
use Sub::Name       qw( subname );
 
{
   my $old = \&Kernel::Module1::some_sub_or_method;

   my $new = subname some_sub_or_method => sub {
      ...

      $old->();   # Optionally call original sub/method.

      ...
   };

   no warnings qw( redefine );
   *Kernel::Module1::some_sub_or_method = $new;
}

1
```

Comment: Monkey patching seems to solve my problem. Thanks! The only problem is a deep recursion when calling the old subroutine inside the new one.

Comment: I showed you how to call the old subroutine (`$old->()`).

Answer (score 1):

@ikegami answer led me to a solution using Class::Monkey lib which allowed me to call the original method without errors:

.\main.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '.';
use lib './Custom';

use Kernel::Module1Patch;

my $module1 = Kernel::Module1Patch->new();

print $module1->subRoutine();
```

.\Kernel\Module1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Kernel::Module1;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub subRoutine {
  return "original";
}
1;
```

.\Custom\Kernel\Module1Patch:

```
package Kernel::Module1Patch;

use Class::Monkey qw<Kernel::Module1>;
 
# The patch
around 'subRoutine' => sub {
    my $originalSubRoutine = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    return 'around' . $self->$originalSubRoutine(@_);
},
qw<Kernel::Module1>;
# /The Patch

1;
```

Return result:

```
aroundoriginal
```

Comment: Yeah, same thing, just using a module. Note that Class::Monkey doesn't use `subname` or similar, so you'll get less useful stack traces on error. (You'll see `__ANON__` in them.) You're also still using the buggy `use lib '.', './Custom';` instead of `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin, "$RealBin/Custom";` .